# Change container port in docker compose

Tags: docker, apache-spark, airflow

I am trying to get a docker-compose file working with both airflow and spark. Airflow typically runs on `8080:8080` which is needed by spark as well. I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    master:
      image: gettyimages/spark
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h master
      hostname: master
      environment:
        MASTER: spark://master:7077
        SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
        SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
      expose:
        - 7001
        - 7002
        - 7003
        - 7004
        - 7005
        - 7077
        - 6066
      ports:
        - 4040:4040
        - 6066:6066
        - 7077:7077
        - 8080:8080
      volumes:
        - ./conf/master:/conf
        - ./data:/tmp/data

    worker:
      image: gettyimages/spark
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
      hostname: worker
      environment:
        SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
        SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
        SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
        SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
        SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
        SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
      links:
        - master
      expose:
        - 7012
        - 7013
        - 7014
        - 7015
        - 8881
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      volumes:
        - ./conf/worker:/conf
        - ./data:/tmp/data
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=y
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Add this to have third party packages
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8082:8080" # NEED TO CHANGE THIS LINE
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

but specifically need to change the line:

```
ports:
    - "8082:8080" # NEED TO CHANGE THIS LINE
```

under web server so there's no port conflict. However when I change the container port to something other than `8080:8080` it doesnt work (cannot connect/find server). How do I change the container port successfully?

Comment: I don't understand - if your webserver is accessible in localhost:8082 and spark with localhost:8080, what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know, im pretty new to docker so maybe nothing? but doesnt the fact that they're 8080:8080 and 8082:8080 create a container port conflict? I am fully prepared to be wrong here btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specified port mapping in docker you are giving 2 ports, for instance: `8082:8080`.
The right port is the one that is listening within the container.
You can have several containers that listening internally to the same port. They are still not available in your localhost - that's why we use the `ports` section for.

Now, in your localhost you cannot bind the same port more than once. That's why docker failed when you try to set on the left side `8080` more than one time.
In your current compose file, the `spark` service port is mapped to 8080 (left side of `8080:8080`) and the `webserver` service is mapped to `8082` (left side of `8082:8080`).

if you want to access spark, goto: http://localhost:8080 and for the web server, go to http://localhost:8082

Comment: thank you, this was helpful. when I try to run a pyspark job I get the error "Java gateway process ended before sending its port number" Any idea how to fix that? if not, I will make a separate question

Comment: What is the solution for this ? Can this conflict be monitored in docker log ?

Comment: @DBA108642 that's a different question, but internally, if two containers want to talk with each other they should use the container name and the "real" internal port. For example, if `worker` wants to talk with `master` it should use master:<some_port>. Hope that's help

Comment: thanks, I think it is more appropriate to ask in a different question,

Comment: @mountainLion the conflict is identified by docker-compose before the `up` command